# How does bullet physics filter 4+ contacts in GJK?

Tags: c++, physics, python, bullet-physics

If the bullet GJK (Convex vs convex) collision algorithm has more than four penetrating points, then how is it filtering that down to the four it needs?

*What I've tried*

- *Staring at the code, but I get confused at this part.*
- *I figure it keeps the deepest penetration somehow*

Comment: We can only answer one question per post, so the questions about other algorithms and supporting concave shapes will need to be asked separately. I have some past answers that might help at a high level, [comparing convex and concave collision detection algorithms](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/205424/39518) and [sketching an algorithm to find the closest point on a concave mesh](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/154708/39518). Expect this to get much slower though, so dividing into approximately convex pieces is often a better option.

Answer (score 0):

It uses a heuristic which selects which point of the existing four that should be replaced by the new point. This heuristic function produces a value that's proportional to an approximation of the contact surface area, i.e. two triangles that form the quadrilateral with the four contact points. It goes over each possibility, replacing one point at a time by the new point and finds which configuration maximizes contact area. And yes, it also prioritizes the deepest point. This helps prevent the deepest from being replaced which would result in visible penetration.

Another possible heuristic is to maximize the surface area of the tetrahedron formed by the four points, which is what I do in my physics engine and I get satisfying results. By consequence, this method chooses to keep the deepest point since it results in a bigger tetrahedron with larger surface area.